# HTML font size changes after loading alert window through Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a basic PHP web form to save data into [mssql](/questions/tagged/mssql) database.
After updating database, a javascript alert message popup appear to show message that data is saved successfully. When I click on the OK button it returns back to the same page, But the page font size is increased. 
I have tried to set the font size in body tag, but still does not works.

```
    <body style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" text="#003399">

</body>

<?php  echo "<script> alert ('Successfully Saved'); </script>";?>
```

Comment: since i have never ever seen this happen elsewhere - you need to show a working proof. https://jsfiddle.net/ would be a good place to put it

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the reply. please view the page at http://blacka.mahenbagrecha.com/CType.php

Comment: In addition to the place of the `script` tag in your document, I would like to suggest to attach a URL query string with a message and unique id to the response to prevent reinsert on refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is by outputting the script tag above the docutype, your rendering the page as invalid html. The browser is then ignoring the css you have set and using the defaults.

Fix: script tags should be inside the  `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: Script tags that produce an alert should never be in the head. Alerts halt all page activity, including rendering. But you are right, it should not be before the doctype, but in body.

Comment: @MueR good call, js is not my specialty. fell free to edit the answer if you like

Comment: You guys are realy great. I just move the doctype before <?php > start tag at start of page. & Its works excelent.